# Adding cell with quotePrefix in POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to add a cell in xlsx workbooks sheet containing the quote prefix, and i am trying to create that sheet using POI library. How do I add this type of cell

I found a reference to this with CTXf.setQuotePrefix(boolean quotePrefix) on maven central, but dont know how to add this to the XSSFCell

I have tried using below code

```
XSSFCell cell=row.createCell(cellIndex);
CTXfImpl ctxf= new CTXfImpl(XmlObject.Factory.newInstance().schemaType());
ctxf.setQuotePrefix(true);
cell.getCTCell().set(ctxf);
cell.setCellValue(data);
```

getting exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTXfImpl.setQuotePrefix(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: I meant your whole code.

Comment: whole code would be too big to post. Below is the code snippet with which i am trying to create XSSFCell in an existing row, then go through the steps to add quoteprefix to the cell and then add data. If I use cell.setCellValue("'" + data), then after the excel is updated, i have to open it with Excel and then double click it so that only the text following the ' is displayed in the cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CTXf` and also the `quotePrefix` property is part of the `XSSFCellStyle` and not the `XSSFCell`.

So we must create a `XSSFCellStyle`, set the `quotePrefix` **there** and then apply this `XSSFCellStyle` to the `XSSFCell`.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class WriteQuotePrefix {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

   CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
   ((XSSFCellStyle)style).getCoreXf().setQuotePrefix(true);

   Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellStyle(style);
   cell.setCellValue("1234");

   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("WriteQuotePrefix.xlsx");
   wb.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.close();

  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding this! FYI, there's [now an easier way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40421281/685641) as it's on [CellStyle now](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setQuotePrefixed(boolean))