# Avoid formula injection, keeping cell value (quote prefix in HSSF/*.xls)

Tags: java, apache-poi

The application I am working on creates Excel exports using Apache POI. It was brought to our attention, through a security audit, that cells containing malicious values can spawn arbitrary processes if the user is not careful enough.

**To reproduce**, run the following:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

public class BadWorkbookCreator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try(
            Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/workbook-bad.xls")
        ) {
            Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet");
            Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Aaaaaaaaaa");
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue("-2+3 +cmd|'/C calc'!G20");
            wb.write(fos);
        }
    }
}
```

Then open the resulting file:

[image: Screenshot to reproduce problem]

And follow these steps:

1. Click on (A) to select the cell with malicious content
2. Click on (B) so that the cursor is in the formula editor
3. Press ENTER
4. You will be asked if you allow Excel to run an external application; if you answer yes, Calc is launched (or any malicious code)

One may say that the user is responsible for letting Excel run arbitrary things and the user was warned. But still, the Excel is downloaded from a trusted source and someone may fall into the trap.

Using Excel, you can place a single quote in front of the text in the formula editor to escape it. Placing the single quote in the cell content programmatically (e.g. code as below) makes the single quote visible!

```
String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
if( cellValue != null && "=-+@".indexOf(cellValue.charAt(0)) >= 0 ) {
    cell.setCellValue("'" + cellValue);
}
```

**The question**: Is there a way to keep the value escaped in the formula editor, but show the correct value, without the leading single quote, in the cell?

[image: Desired outcome, when hand-edited with Excel]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806098/adding-cell-with-quoteprefix-in-poi/39808020#39808020 for XSSF (`*.xlsx`). No clue how for HSSF (`*.xls`).

Comment: Thank you @AxelRichter for pointing the way to go, i.e. the *style*. Digging into debug, it seems that what I want can be accomplished by using `ExtendedFormatRecord.set123Prefix(true)`. The problems of course is (1) this is undocumented and (2) the `ExtendedFormatRecord _format` field of `HSSFCellStyle` is private without any accessor! The remaining options seem to be to either switch to xlsx format, file a change request in the POI project, or hack :) Unless of course there is another solution I am not aware of.

Comment: Would you expect to find a suitable method on `CellStyle` called `set123Prefix(true)` (as  with low level HSSF) or `setQuotePrefix(true)` (as with low level XSSF) - before we go add it based on Axel's hard investigation work!

Comment: Hi @Gagravarr, thanks for the attention. I am not familiar with the semantics of "123prefix". Actually I found it while debugging and stepping into POI code and observing the various bit operations. So, if I am representative of the average user, I would say "123prefix" is not a good name. On the other hand `setQuotePrefix()` is descriptive *and* in line with XSSF, so I definitely vote for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the hard work investigating of [Axel Richter here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806098/adding-cell-with-quoteprefix-in-poi/39808020#39808020) and [Nikos Paraskevopoulos here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40406844/685641)....

From Apache POI 3.16 beta 1 onwards (or for those who live dangerously, any nightly build after 20161105), there are handy methods on [CellStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html) for [getQuotePrefixed](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#getQuotePrefixed()) and [setQuotePrefixed(boolean)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setQuotePrefixed(boolean))

Your code could then become:

```
// Do this once for the workbook
CellStyle safeFormulaStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
safeFormulaStyle.setQuotePrefixed(true);


// Per cell
String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
if( cellValue != null && "=-+@".indexOf(cellValue.charAt(0)) >= 0 ) {
    cell.setCellStyle(safeFormulaStyle);
}
```

Comment: It would be better to Trim field before checking first char.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to the *instant* (kudos) response from the POI team (see accepted answer), this solution should be obsolete. Keeping it as a reference, could be useful in cases an upgrade to POI >= 3.16 is not possible.**

---

Thanks to the comment of Axel Richter (for which I am very-very thankful) I managed to work out a solution. It is definitely NOT as straightforward as in the case of XLSX files (`XSSFWorkbook`), because it involves creating the `org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook` by hand; this class is marked as `@Internal` by the POI project, but is `public` as far as Java is concerned. Additionally, the field that is set to correct the problem, i.e. `ExtendedFormatRecord.set123Prefix(true)` is not documented!

Here is the solution, for what it's worth - compare it with the code in the question:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.ExtendedFormatRecord;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

public class GoodWorkbookCreator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InternalWorkbook internalWorkbook = InternalWorkbook.createWorkbook();
        try(
            HSSFWorkbook wb = HSSFWorkbook.create(internalWorkbook);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/workbook-good.xls")
        ) {
            HSSFCellStyle style = (HSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
            ExtendedFormatRecord xfr = internalWorkbook.getExFormatAt(internalWorkbook.getNumExFormats() - 1);
            xfr.set123Prefix(true); // THIS IS WHAT IT IS ALL ABOUT

            Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet");
            Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Aaaaaaaaaa");
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue("-2+3 +cmd|'/C calc'!G20");
            Cell cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue("-2+3 +cmd|'/C calc'!G20");
            cell.setCellStyle(style);
            wb.write(fos);
        }
    }
}
```