# How to precede cell value with hidden apostrophe using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Please help me, I want to add hidden apostrophe using apache poi.
I'am trying to use this code, but it doesn't work. The apostrophe still shown.

```
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cell.setCellValue("'"+obj.getDepartementCode());
```

Result:

[image]

Result that i want:

[image]

Comment: what is a *hidden apostrophe* ?

Comment: what i mean is apostrophe character that only show in formula bar but not in cell, I added a screenshot image that shows what I mean, thanks for your response btw

Comment: This is called `quotePrefix`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806098/adding-cell-with-quoteprefix-in-poi/39808020#39808020. And now in current versions: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setQuotePrefixed(boolean)

Comment: @Axel Richter Thank you so much, its working now. i move from POI 3.9 to POI 3.16 and use method setQuotePrefix(true).